# Android Webveiw:My HTML Content is Overlapping

Tags: android, webview

My HTML Content is Overlapping in Webview when i set  transparent Background.

`webview.setBackgroundColor(0);`

Thanks

Comment: Post a link to the HTML content and a screenshot of the overlapping content.